# How to replace date string in a file?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a date "12/12/2013" in a file, i want it to be replaced by MM/DD/YYYY literally.

file

```
Date: 12/12/2013             Shipment
Name: xxxx ................
```

i want it as

```
Date: MM/DD/YYYY             Shipment
Name: xxxx................
```

Comment: Please note: i dont want today's date in here.  I just want the above value "12/12/2013" to be changed as "MM/DD/YYYY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
sed -i 's_12/12/2013_MM/DD/YYYY_' file name
```

Else.

```
sed 's_12/12/2013_MM/DD/YYYY_' file name > filename
```

Comment: The thing is there are other dates as well they are also getting changed.

Comment: @user215827 Now you got the exact need?

Comment: Yes Thank you! Currently it is getting displayed on screen how to save it in the same file?

Comment: @user215827 You can use the option -i. See the edited answer.

Comment: Getting below error:
sed: illegal option -- i
Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...]

I'm using hp nonstop box

Comment: @user215827 You can redirect the output to the file.

Comment: Yeah that would be the last option i guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (the delimiter can be any character, not limited to default `/`; Here I use `@`):

```
sed -i.bak 's@Date:\s*12/12/2013@Date: MM/DD/YYYY@' file
```

or

```
sed -i.bak 's@12/12/2013@MM/DD/YYYY@' file
```

The basic skeleton of a `sed` substitution is : `s///`

Comment: I literally want MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @AvinashRaj He's not parsing dates, he's replacing one hard-coded string with another.

Comment: How can this be achieved just by using "12/12/2013" instead of @Date:\s*12/12/2013 ??

Comment: I'm working on hp unix, and its throwing error sed function cannot be parsed.

Comment: Try with -e: `sed -e "s@Date:\s*12/12/2013@Date: MM/DD/YYYY@" file`

Comment: Have you read my answer until the end ? Have you read `man sed` ?

Comment: Yes, Getting below error: 

sed: illegal option -- i Usage: sed [-n] [-e script] [-f source_file] [file...] I'm using hp nonstop box

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's#[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{4\}#MM/DD/YYYY#'
```

matches 2 digits followed by `/` followed by 2 digits and `/` and finally 4 digits, then replace pattern with `MM/DD/YYYY`